# InfluxDB - Kapacitor output as SNMP trap

Tags: snmp, influxdb, kapacitor

I am new to SNMP and to Kapacitor-InfluxDB. I have InfluxDB and Kapacitor installed on a server. Kapacitor is generating alarms using data pushed into InfluxDB. I was wondering if it is possible to consider the server on which Kapacitor and InfluxDB are installed an SNMP agent and use the alarms that Kapacitor generates as traps to be sent to an SNMP manager installed on a separate machine? 
Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it as an Output Node in Kapacitor: https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v0.13/about_the_project/custom_output/

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your response. I will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Kapacitor can not natively send SNMP traps out of the box (yet). That functionality will likely require adding an SNMP trap event handler to the [alert node](http://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.0/nodes/alert_node/).

Kapacitor's alert node [exec](http://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.0/nodes/alert_node/#exec) event handler can be set to trigger a SNMP trap via [`snmptrap`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/snmptrap1.html) or another SNMP command line agent.

Comment: Hi Gunnar, thank you for your response. I think I get the idea.